# django-ckeditor non staff member image upload

Tags: django

I have deployed my site and want regular (logged in) users to be able to upload images, how to do this is described on git homepage/readme:

1. Add CKEditor URL include to your project's urls.py file:
2. (r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
   Note that by adding those URLs you add views that can upload and browse through uploaded images. Since django-ckeditor 4.4.6 those views are staff_member_required. If you want different permission decorator (login_required, user_passes_test etc.) then add views defined in ckeditor.urls manually to your urls.py.

and here is my urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /reports/5/
    url(r'^(?P<report_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^create/$', views.create, name='create'),
    url(r'^create2/$', views.reportsparticipants, name='reportsparticipants'),
    url(r'^addparticipants/$', views.addparticipants, name='addparticipants'),
    url(r'^(?P<report_id>[0-9]+)/like/$', views.like, name='like'),
    url(r'^(?P<report_id>[0-9]+)/dislike/$', views.dislike, name='dislike'),
    url(r'^deleteparticipant/(?P<part_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.deleteparticipant, name='deleteparticipant'),
    url(r'^modify/(?P<report_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.modify, name='modify'),
    url(r'^modifyparticipants/(?P<report_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.modifyparticipants, name='modifyparticipants'),
    url(r'^deleteparticipantmodify/(?P<part_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<report_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.deleteparticipantmodify, name='deleteparticipantmodify'),
    url(r'^reportadded/$', views.reportadded, name='reportadded'),
    url(r'^commented/(?P<report_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.commented, name='commented'),
    url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
    #url(r'^liked/(?P<report_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.liked, name='liked'),
    url(r'^dc/$', views.dc, name='dc'),
]
```

I can't think of the appropriate changes to my urls.py file for the desired state described in step 2

Answer (score 1):

```
# urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    # Your urlpatterns...
]


from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from ckeditor_uploader.views import upload

urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^ckeditor/upload/', login_required(upload), name='ckeditor_upload'),
    url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
]
```

This gonna work